# WebSocket handshake failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-websocket

My application is a Spring boot app which uses Spring WebSocket with STOMP. All the configurations are working fine in my local. But getting the following error in the cloud.

**Server Error :-**

> ERROR o.s.w.s.s.s.DefaultHandshakeHandler - Handshake failed due to
>   invalid Upgrade header: null

**Client Error :- In the browser :-**

> WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://.example.com/ws/313/7pq61a2c/websocket' failed:
>   Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I deployed in AWS cloud with ELB. My instance is running on HTTP with HTTPS enabled in ELB. I use AWS route 53 for my domain.

I have added a 'A' record with the LoadBalancer URL in route 53.

HTTPS certificate is for *.example.com.

**ELB is been configured with the following,**

> HTTP  - 80  - HTTP - 80
>
> HTTPS - 443 - HTTP - 80

I did googling and found that I need to increase the idle timeout. User might keep the session open for 8 hours. 
So, Do I need to configure it for 8 hours?
Is there any other configuration should be done in ELB?

Though we run our EC2 instance on HTTP, we have a filter which redirects user back to HTTPS based on the X-Forward_Proto header.

In the debug logs logs, I see http://example.com:80/ws/313/7pq61a2c/websocket

Could that be the reason?

How can I configure websocket to try with https not http?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that AWS ELB doesn't support web sockets at the moment.

You can check these links:

1. https://blog.jverkamp.com/2015/07/20/configuring-websockets-behind-an-aws-elb/
2. https://www.built.io/blog/2014/11/websockets-on-aws-elb/

Hope this helps.